# Bone driver on X location not working

Tags: bones, constraints, drivers, shape-keys, axis

I created a bone and added copy location, and limit location constraint with world space, because when I selected local space, the bone didn't even move, this works fine and the limitations too, but the driver don't. I set a average value driver for when this bone moves on x location to apply a corrective shape key, I tried local space and world space in the driver, but when the bone moves forward on X nothing changes. I've been trying to work this out during one day, and I got a lot of different wrong results, sometimes the value is 1000 in rest pose, and when I move the bone forward it goes to 0, I tried a lot of combinations using the generator modifier and didn't got any success. I want the shape key value to get to 1000 when i move the leg forward, and literally go to 0 when i move it backwards

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Display the bone axis.**

[image]
*Driver limited from 0 to 2 moving in Z local direction of bone.*

Locally for bones the Y axis goes down the axis of the bone. If you enable the display in armature display properties can turn this on.

The copy location constraint is a bit arbitrary between pose (wrt armature origin) and global.

For the limit location constraint going to use local. The zero of a local transform is its rest position.  Ok can set the minimum to 0.  Looking at bone axis then +Z is forward, have limited it to 2.  *An arbitrary choice for this answer and to test against, change to suit.*

[image]

To change the result to go from 0 to 4 with a generator

[image]

which is the equivalent of having a scripted expression for the driver of

```
0 + 2 * var
```

which if you remember basic algebra is a linear equation.  *As mentioned by @Nathan in other answer, this was and issue because it was set to be result zero, no matter what the value of var was.*

1000 seems to me to be an outrageously big result, but for this example would use 500 instead of 2.

**See driver results.**

Find it handy to use the script from  this answer when fiddling with drivers

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199299/15543

can test the value of a number of variables by looking at output in console, rather than via the driver editor UI.

Answer (score 0):

Look on the modifiers tab for your driver.  You've created an "expanded polynomial" modifier for your driver, in replace rather than additive mode, that locks your driver value to 0 because of its settings.  Delete this modifier and your driver works (although what you're going for, I don't know.)

[image]

Comment: I deleted the driver, the same problem persist, when i move the leg forward, the value decrease, when i move it back, it increase, and then decrease, i want the shape key value to get to 1000 when i move the leg forward, and literally go to 0 when i move it backwards

Comment: @Silly3D Edit your question to provide that information, so that you're asking the question you want the answer to.