# How to get the angle of an object at each frame

Tags: animation, physics, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, command-line

In an animation of an object how will I get the real time angle value for an object at each frame. Is there any command for that just like for the location `{bpy.data.objects['obj'].matrix_world.translation()}`?
At any frame I am trying to get the angle value but it is giving the intial value even though the object has been rotated at that frame.

Comment: Please specify where you need to use this angle, in a script, in a driver? What do the curly braces denote? In what form do you need the angles? Quaternion? Euler? Radians, degrees?

Comment: `matrix_world.to_euler()`  or `to_quaternion()` or `to_3x3()`

Comment: matrix_world.to_euler() just gives the intial angles of the object. I want the real time angles at each frame in the animation.  I am able to get the real time loaction using matrix_world.translation but don't know how to do the same for the angles.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215493/non-wrapping-rigid-body-rotations  Consider adding more info re your setup, _eg_ physics and command line.