# How to visualize a mesh object's position during a (rigid body) simulation

Tags: python, mesh, objects, rigid-body-simulation

Is there an automated way to visualize a mesh object's position during a (rigid body) simulation?
I have six spheres rolling a circular track, passing predefined points. I would like to show their position (textually somewhere in the viewport, 1,2,3..etc.) when those spheres pass those points.
Is that possible in Blender, for example with Python?
Or only possible to do this manually?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can use Python, but setting text data requires elevated privileges (enable script autoexecution, with security considerations I mention [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243271/60486)) - it's clunky…

A modern (3.0) alternative is Geometry Nodes:

[image]

[image]

You could even do something fancy using Simulation Nodes in Blender 3.6:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to use Python, you will find examples here:

[Non-wrapping rigid body rotations?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/215493/60486)

Answer (score 0):

Open motion paths section in object data:

[image]

You can select different frame range, by default it is scene frame range.

Then it's done, click calculate button, you will see a path like this:

[image]

Different options are available in Display subpannel:

[image]