accessing computed output value from a "NodeSocketFloat" bpy_struct in a GeometryNodes network
I see this same question without no "satisfactory" reply, so i'll just throw it there again.
¿Is it possible to access a value from an output socket of type ? I see many properties out there for the node, except for the one i am really looking for.
¿How to you access it, for instance, via Python?

I tried many ways of accessing the property, this one i found the most intuitive but it is not working:


As correctly stated by the guys in blender.chat, the #python channel, storing attributes in Curve Shapes is not useful because it cannot be retrieved. In order to be able to use an attribute that you have previously stored onto the geometry, you need to store it in a Mesh Shape/Transform object type.
So the solution for me, was to create a new Node Group with all the GN Network and reuse it in a "dummy" geometry cube where, with its own GN network, i would inject the stored value into a new "Store Named Attribute" this time on the cube Mesh Shape.... and voilà.
Having understood this, the next step is to use a function that reads the "AngleBetweenVectors" parameter and substracts it to the "offset" parameter of a Follow Path Constraint. This, done by means of a Driver.
This last step is making Blender 4.1.1 crash when i hit "update dependencies". Not sure yet what the problem could be. Most probably with the "evaluation of the graph", being it maybe "cyclic". Not sure yet.

i found the solution in this post (to the last problem of evaluating the depsgraph): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242227/accessing-geometry-nodes-attributes-in-drivers

Dont retrieve the depsgraph from the bpy.context, but rather, use the "depsgraph" available variable to be passed on to your driver function as an input parameter. This changes everything.
